# Push to feature branch without merging

Tags: git

My project has a `master`, `develop` and feature branches. I started a new feature branch `issue-141` forked from `develop` and made 3 commits to it. When I push from this feature branch I would expect the commits to be pushed to `origin/issue-141`, but instead it tries to push to `develop` (which I don't have access to). Can someone explain to me why this is happening? Why can't I simply push to the same `issue-141` branch remotely?

This is the output from `git remote show origin`:

```
  * remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/XXX
  Push  URL: https://github.com/XXX
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop                tracked
    external_http_enricher tracked
    issue-141              tracked
    master                 tracked
    partijgedrag           tracked
    production             tracked
    v0                     tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop   merges with remote develop
    issue-141 merges with remote issue-141
    master    merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop   pushes to develop   (up to date)
    issue-141 pushes to issue-141 (up to date)
    master    pushes to master    (local out of date)
```

Comment: run `git branch` and check what you're actually working on.

Comment: also have you `--set-upstream` the feature branch so that remote can keep track of it?

Comment: @jsarbour the dropdown in PyCharm says I'm on `origin/issue-141`

Comment: and does remote track the feature branch?

Comment: Can you post the output of the command `git remote show origin` (specifically the `Local refs configured for 'git push':` section so we can see your upstream refs?

Comment: @strwils I have added the output to the question

Comment: @voodoo-burger git has your local branch properly configured to push to the remote `issue-141` branch. If you are using a GUI tool on top of git it is possible something in the configuration of that tool is wrong. But if you are using git from the command line, a simple `git push` command should work, but you can also use `git push origin issue-141:issue-141` to make the local and remote branches explicit.

Comment: *"but instead it tries to push to `develop` (which I don't have access to)"* How do you know that? Can you show us the message?

Comment: It's not possible to be "on" a remote-tracking name, in Git. I don't know what PyCharm is showing you here. (Passing an actual remote-tracking name to `git checkout` results in what Git calls a "detached HEAD".)

Comment: Well the issue seems to have magically resolved itself... Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Maybe not "magically": it seems that I can push to the feature branch *after* I create the Github pull request.